# Using NAudio how do I save Non-interlaced 32-bit float format to file

Tags: c#, wav, naudio

In C#, I am trying to save off PCM data to a WAV file.  Using NAudio, I create a WaveFileWriter.

```
this.fileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(@"c:\temp\test.wav", new WaveFormat(this.audioParameters.SampleRate, this.channels));
```

I am capturing the PCM packet in a float array and write the samples.

```
var arraySize = noOfFrames * this.channels;
var buffer = new float[arraySize];
Marshal.Copy(data, buffer, 0, arraySize);
this.fileWriter?.WriteSamples(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

The outputted audio file is of the proper length but the audio is sounds horrible.  I can tell it is the same audio but it is not right.

```
// Non-interlaced 32-bit float format
// ChannelLayout = LayoutStereo
// FramesPerBuffer = 1024
// SampleRate = 44100
// channels = 2
```

In NAudio, how do I create a WAV file from a PCM stream with the above information?

Answer (score 2):

You are putting 32 bit floating point audio samples into a 16 bit WAV file. Use `WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(sampleRate, channels)` for the `WaveFormat` of the `WaveFileWriter`.